# Importing a function in a management command for unit testing

Tags: django

I have a management command called dorecall in an app called person. Inside this dorecall command code, there is a function called `send_email(self, person)` that I'd like to test. How do I import this function (or the dorecall module) in my test.py so I can test it with the `django.test` framework?

Here is what happens when I import:

```
(person)bob@sh ~/code/person/person/dapi $  > python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jan  3 2012, 11:40:38)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
>>> import person.management.dorecall
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named dorecall
```

Here is the relevant structure of the app:

```
 ./
 ├── person
 │   ├── __init__.py
 │   ├── forms.py
 │   ├── management
 │   │   ├── __init__.py
 │   │   └── commands
 │   │       ├── __init__.py
 │   │       ├── dorecall.py
 │   │       └── dorecall.pyc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dorecall.py` resides in `person > management > commands > dorecall.py`. So the import should be:

```
import person.management.commands.dorecall
```